# Will leaving condensation on a cup keep it cool longer than wiping it?

Tags: thermodynamics

If I have a plastic cup with a cold drink in it, is it theoretically better to leave the condensation on the outside of the cup or is it better to keep removing it? Will one way keep my drink cooler for longer?

Answer (score 1):

Very slightly.

The condensation is symptomatic of energy being given to the cup by water vapour, and this causes warming. The rate of energy transfer depends on a number of factors, including the external surface area of the cup, and the air flow rate past it (if any).

Condensation on the cup effectively increases the bodies thermally conductive surface area, if only by a small amount. This will increase the rate of further condensation compared with a cup at the same temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it will help keep the cup colder for two reasons:

1. The difference temperature between the condensed water and the cup is lower than the difference with humidity in the air and as the temperature difference increases the rate of change of heat increases.
2. The condensation will keep happening again no matter how many times you wipe, it is a natural distribution of energy which is going to lead to increased entropy and can't be stopped in the universe i live in.